# How to show list of installed extensions for firefox via command line?

Tags: command-line, firefox

What is the command line to show the list of all installed extensions on the firefox browser? Is there any. I checked `man firefox` but did not help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Give a try to this `grep` oneliner command to list all the firefox addons,

```
grep -oP '(?<=\},\"name\":\")([^"]*)' ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/addons.json
```

**OR**

This worked for me:

```
user@host:~$ cat ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/addons.json |
python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);
for (i, x) in enumerate(obj["addons"]):
  print x["name"]' | uniq
```

Output in my case:

```
Clean Links
Tee-Timer
```

**Explanation**:

- `cat ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/addons.json`: reads the addons.json file in each profile.
- `python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);` load the json parser library of python and loads json via stdin (standard input), ergo from `cat`
- `for (i, x) in enumerate(obj["addons"]):` phyton code to loop through the array of addons...
- `print x["name"]' | uniq` ...and print its name only one.

Comment: OMG, would please put some description on them

Comment: @alex see my edit

Comment: This is very good (+1) but needlessly complex. You don't need to escape the `"` in your regex and you also don't really need the lookbehind. There is no guarantee that the home dir will be `/home/$(whoami)` it could be anywhere. A better approach would be to use `~/` or `$HOME`.  There's no point in finding the default profile name either. It will always end in `.default` and even if there are more, you can parse all of them and pass through `uniq`. The `USER=user` is pointless, there is already a global variable called `USER` that holds your username.

Comment: @terdon good points, thanks. I edited the answer again...

Comment: The Python version choked on an extension with an accented character. But the grep version, and also terdon's shorter grep version both work fine.

Answer (score 8):

This is basically just a simplified version of @chaos's approach:

```
grep -oP '},"name":"\K[^"]*' ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/addons.json
```

There's no reason to get the name of the user, you can always just use `~/` or `$HOME` to get the home directory. The name of the default profile is, likewise, unneeded. You probably only have one and its name will be `RandomString.default`. If you have more than one, and different addons for each, this approach will list *all* of them. So, if you *do* have multiple profiles, you might want to add `| uniq` to the above command to remove duplicates.

#### Explanation

- `grep -oP` : the `-o` causes `grep` to only print the matched portion of the line and the `-P` activates Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which are needed for the `\K` (see below).
- `},"name":"\K[^"]*`: match the longest stretch of non-`"` characters (`[^"]*`) that come right after `},"name":`. The `\K` means "ignore everything matched up to here" which, when combined with `-o`, will cause only the part of the match after the `name:":"` to be printed.
- `~/` : this is your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Following scriptlet is just a more-featureful version of [@chaos's code](https://askubuntu.com/a/485804/116758). My motivations were

- I use more than one Firefox profile.
- I put my Firefox profiles in a different dir/folder than the default: see `FIREFOX_PROFILE_ROOT` in script/let, which you should probably edit (back to the default), or use the newer `profiles.ini`-parsing code (see link below).
- I wanted to see more information about my add-ons, since I was having a problem that turned out to be extension-version-related.
- I just hadn't coded for a few days `:-)`

You can also {see the latest version of this code, use the latest version as a downloadable script file} [here](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/firefox_utils/src/HEAD/list_addons.sh?at=master). Note the newer code also parses `profiles.ini` (using the profile paths you define there) rather than relying (as below) on you telling the code where to find your profiles.

```
### List add-ons in all local Firefox profiles. Requires:

### * users to know where they keep their Firefox profiles. TODO: parse `profiles.ini`
### * python (to parse the add-ons JSON)

### Tested on Linux with Python versions={2.7.9, 3.4.2}.

### Copyright (C) 2017 Tom Roche <Tom_Roche@pobox.com>
### This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License.
### To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/

#FIREFOX_PROFILE_ROOT="${HOME}/.mozilla/firefox"  # default Firefox path, which ...
FIREFOX_PROFILE_ROOT="${HOME}/firefox"           # ... I override, but you probably should not!
FIREFOX_ADDONS_FILENAME='addons.json'            # default Firefox value
FIREFOX_ADDONS_FP_LIST=''                        # default empty

### find add-ons JSON files:

if  [[ ! -r "${FIREFOX_PROFILE_ROOT}" ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "ERROR: cannot read FIREFOX_PROFILE_ROOT='${FIREFOX_PROFILE_ROOT}', exiting ..."
else

    FIREFOX_ADDONS_FP_LIST="$(find "${FIREFOX_PROFILE_ROOT}/" -type f -name "${FIREFOX_ADDONS_FILENAME}" | fgrep -ve 'blocklists')"
#    echo -e "FIREFOX_ADDONS_FP_LIST=\n${FIREFOX_ADDONS_FP_LIST}" # debugging


    if   [[ ( -z "${FIREFOX_ADDONS_FP_LIST}" ) ||
            ( "$(echo ${FIREFOX_ADDONS_FP_LIST} | wc -l)" == '0' ) ]] ; then
        >&2 echo "ERROR: found no add-ons files in Firefox profiles under '${FIREFOX_PROFILE_ROOT}', exiting ..."
    else

        for FIREFOX_ADDONS_FP in ${FIREFOX_ADDONS_FP_LIST} ; do
            echo "${FIREFOX_ADDONS_FP} contains:"
            ### Parse add-ons file using python, so
            ### * gotta export the envvar
            export FIREFOX_ADDONS_FP
            ### * indenting becomes important

            python -c '
import json, os
with open(os.environ.get("FIREFOX_ADDONS_FP")) as addons_file:
    addons_data = json.load(addons_file)
    for (i, addon) in enumerate(addons_data["addons"]):
        print("add-on name=" + addon["name"])
        print("    version=" + addon["version"])
        print("        URI=" + addon["learnmoreURL"])
        print("") # newline
'

            echo # newline
        done
    fi
fi
```

Comment: please don't leave comments advertising your (fine) answer on other answers. Your answer is just as visible and you're just spamming the other answerers.

Answer (score 1):

[`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is the simpler way to process JSON data.

> `jq` is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor.

```sh
jq -j '.addons [] | ( .type, ",", .defaultLocale.name, ",", .active, "\n" )' ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default-*/extensions.json | sort -u
```

`addons.json` doesn't contain 'active' flag (if it's enabled/disabled).

They are also listed on `about:support`.

I still want to filter more, just active extensions names and their sourceURI without *search.mozilla.org* ones (as probably OP wants).

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51028270/4970442). [Related](https://superuser.com/q/263422/500826).